# Visual Studio 2008 not responding when dealing with large number of tests

Tags: c#, performance, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008

We are working with Visual Studio 2008 in a solution with 128 projects, almost half of them are unit test projects which make a total number of more than 5000 unit tests. For that reason we usually leave all unit test projects unloaded except those ones we are working with. Nevertheless, we often suffer from having Visual Studio 2008 blocked whenever we try to launch a single unit test or load/unload a different unit test project. In Task Manager we see that devenv.exe process takes constantly 25% of CPU and through Process Explorer we have seen that devenv.exe is in a loop of CreateFile, QueryBasicInformationFile and CloseFile for each project file loaded in the solution, iterating through all project files over and over again.

We have tried to set in the registry the key HKLM\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\EnterpriseTools\QualityTools\EnableCMI to 0 as it is stated in some forums where we have searched for a solution or workaround, but with no luck.

As a workaround, we are working with solutions that contain only a small subset of projects, but we don´t see it as a definite solution as we don´t consider very 'developer-friendly' to be switching between different solutions and different instances of VS2008 all the time.

Anyone who had experienced this same behavior could give us any clue on how to prevent Visual Studio 2008 from being unresponsive for so much time when dealing with unit tests? It makes developing unit tests almost impossible.

Many thanks in advance.

Jose Antonio

Comment: Do you have any other version of Visual Studio installed?

Answer (score 0):

Consider upgrading Visual Studio. 2008 is ancient and it had serious performance issues in large solutions. 2012 was better, but IIRC a lot of work was done in 2013 to make it workable with a lot of projects.

128 projects in one solution in 2008 times is - ah - challenging it. Not to say totally over the top by factors.

With 2013 it should actually work

There is not a lot you can do here in fact - the problems with a significant number of projects in older versions of Visual Studio are simply documented and were fixed a long time ago - in newer versions.

Comment: Yes, we are planning to upgrade our Visual Studio versión, but not in a near future. We prefer not doing such a change right now to prevent difficulties to meet our schedule due to the potential problems derived from an IDE change. We wanted to know if there is any workaround to work with a large amount of unit tests in VS2008. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: No, there is no workaround. Your version is seriously outdated, and the issue was fixed. Noone (at microsoft) cares about that. THe issues were known and seriously, 128 projects is really taking it to extreme levels. THe workaround IS an IDE upgrade, which whoever is in charge (and obviosuly failed in his job) should have scheduled a long time ago.